# iOS Not receiving Push Notification from CloudKit

Tags: ios, swift3, cloudkit

I'm trying to setup subscriptions for CloudKit Records, the subscription creates OK, I can retrieve it with `CKFetchSubscriptionsOperation` successfully. But the function 
`application(_:didReceiveRemoteNotification:)` doesn't get called...
(I'm changing the records by hand in Dashboard)

The subscription is setted in this way:

```
let database = CKContainer.default().privateCloudDatabase
let subscription = CKSubscription(recordType: "Device", predicate: NSPredicate(format: "TRUEPREDICATE"), options: .firesOnRecordUpdate)

let notificationInfo = CKNotificationInfo()
notificationInfo.alertLocalizationKey = "DEVICE_UPDATED"
notificationInfo.alertBody = "Device updated in database"

subscription.notificationInfo = notificationInfo

database.save(subscription) { subscription, error in
    if error != nil {
        print(error?.localizedDescription as Any)
    } else {
        print(subscription)
    }
}
```

And Registration registration for Notification is:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {        
    let notificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge], categories: nil)
    application.registerUserNotificationSettings(notificationSettings)
    application.registerForRemoteNotifications()

    return true
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any]) {
    print(userInfo)
}
```

Comment: Are you running your app on a real device or the simulator?

Comment: Yup, I tried both

Comment: Notifications don't work on the simulator, but a real device should be ok.  Try implementing `application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) ` in your app delegate. Are you getting a call to `func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data)` ?

Comment: Even the real device doesnt work, so I don't know what I'm doing wrong, I followed this tutorial, and it doesn't work – https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=BXl5o5_2aEU

Comment: I'm not getting called in either of these functions, I enabled Background Modes -> remote-notification but still, I guess there is problem with registering remote notification in general

Comment: Alright, managed to get calling to `func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data)` working, but I'm still not getting any call to `application(_:didReceiveRemoteNotification:)` (I had create certificate for Push Notifications). I'm going to look more into it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I had to enable push notifications and generate "Apple Push Notification service SSL Certificate" and attach it to my app at Apple Developer Provisioning Profiles page

Comment: realy? Is that the case?

Comment: it should not matter actually